# ouputting element name used in $("[ELEMENT]").hide

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

while working on a site i've been getting this message in Firebug

> TypeError: element is null
>
> element.style.display = 'none';

now the error itself it coming from the site's prototype.js file for the hide function

```
hide: function(element) {
element = $(element);
element.style.display = 'none';
return element;
},
```

now because the site compiles all the javascript files into one, one error will stop all the javascript from working, now i figured that someone is trying to use `$("[ELEMENT]").hide` on the site but has misspelled [ELEMENT] or [ELEMENT] has been removed in a recent change

because of how many times `.hide` does come up it's hard to find the problem line of code, so i am wondering, within the hide function i have is there a way to output the name of the element it's trying to find

Comment: `console.log(element)`. Though I'm not sure what this `[ELEMENT]` syntax you keep using is supposed to denote.

Comment: Try looking at the error in the Chrome developer tools. When the error is thrown, you can expand it to see the stack trace.

Comment: @MattBall [ELEMENT] is sup[posed to represent variable data, like 'my-form'

Comment: @Travesty3 while i couldn't get the name of the element the stack trace helped in finding the problem, as i had thought when .hide was used, the element was missing